# Two Column HTML Document Site Map

Tags: html, css, pdf, frameset

I am trying to make a simple two column webpage. 
On the left side is a series of url links. On the right side is where I want the content to be displayed. I don't know if it necessarily matters, but the links on the left open to different pages of a PDF document on the right.

```
<a href="myfile.pdf#page=4">

----------------------------------------
| PDF URL 1    |                       |
| PDF URL 2    |                       |
| PDF URL 3    |                       |
| PDF URL 4    |                       |
|              |    PDF DOC VIEW       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
----------------------------------------
```

Back in my original days of HTML this was no problem using framesets. But that was a few years ago. Are framesets still a viable solution to this? Or is there a better, more currently accepted way using DIVs?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.column {
  height: 100vh;
}

#side {
  float: left;
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 40%;
}

#main {
  float: left;
  background-color: #DDD;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="side" class="column">
      Look at me! I'm at the side
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="column">
      I'm the main div
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Nowadays you'd use div containers and style them with css. I'd recommend to take a look at [twitter's bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: Thanks. But how do I make the URLs in the left div open up a file in the main div?

Comment: That's a little beyond the question. Check out this answer on how to embed PDFs http://stackoverflow.com/a/291823/2434539